# Is it feasible to copy and use python modules from ide to server?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I have developed a python leaning project via PyCharm on my windows machine. 
In this project I have used cx-oracle module to connect to oracle database.

Now I want to try my code to a unix server. I don't have privilege to use pip install or install external modules/packages to support my code.

Hence, my code is not working at the server as it is not able to find and import cx-oracle

I want to know, is there any other feasible way to do it.

I tried by explicitly copying cx_Oracle-7.2.0.dist-info and cx_Oracle.pyd from my project's site-package to my server local directory where I have the main python code file, say main.py

But it didn't work.

P.S. Same method worked for me for tqdm module.

Comment: If `pip install` doesn't work, does `pip install --user`?

Comment: The thing is pip itself is not installed, and I am not the administrator of the server, hence I can't use yum or anything to install modules.

Answer (score 0):

cx_Oracle.pyd is explicitly for Windows and will not work on any platform other than Windows. You can download the cx_Oracle source package from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/#files) and then build cx_Oracle yourself. You can also download the Oracle Instant Client zip files (if you don't already have an Oracle Client or Oracle Database installation present on the server). Check the [installation documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-linux) for help with these steps, if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anthony for source code. So now I have the tar.gz file. Can you please guide me with the process to install the module via this source code. I extracted the source code, and placed the directory at same location of my main.py file. Still I am not able to import cx_oracle. I suspect I need to run setup.py with appropiate command in order to use import cx_oracle. Can you please guide me

Comment: Read the documentation I provided in my first comment! Follow the instructions for building from source.